# Create-react-app & webpack: ошибка конфликт зависимостей

Tags: webpack, зависимости, create-react-app

Установка и запуск:

- npm i -g create-react-app
- create-react-app name
- cd name
- npm start

*Ошибка:
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
  "webpack": "4.19.1"
Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:
  C:\Users\user\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.27.1)*

В package.json версия вебпака не указана. Пробовал указать и переустановить - не помогло.

Comment: Попробуй удалить папку node_modules и в корне прописать npm install

Comment: Не помогло, та же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это конфликт глобальной и локальной версий Webpack. Нужно удалить `node_modules` по этому пути:

```
/Users/home/node_modules
```